# Getting object after json call over different files

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My goal is to change a value from an external object that is set with data from  a json call.

I have an object in file 1(file1.js). this object get's its settings from an outside json file(setting.json). The object retrieves these settings with a json call.

*file1.js*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let example;

    $.getJSON( "setting.json", function(data) {

        // create object based on settings
        example = new ExampleObject(data);

    }).fail(function(e) {
        console.warn(e);
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("ExampleObject after json call: ");
        console.log(example);

        window.exampleObject = example; // is still undefined in other js file cause that runs before this finishes.
    });

    window.exampleObject = example;     // is undefined cause json fetch finishes after setting this.
});

class ExampleObject{
    constructor(settings){
        this.width = settings.width;
        this.height = settings.height;
    }
    setWidth(width){
        this.width = width;
    }
    setHeight(height){
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

*setting.json*

```
{
    "width": 3,
    "height": 4
}
```

This works and all but now i want to get this object from a thirdparty file(file2.js) so i can change some values.

I realise that the object is undefined because file2.js finishes before the json call in file1.js.

I would like file1.js to act independently so file1.js can still run if file2.js would not exist.
So is there a way to wait for a jsoncall in another file so it sets the object correctly globally ?

if not. How would people go about this ?

*file2.js*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // get object from global object
    console.log(window.exampleObject);

    // cant run this line since window.exampleObject is undefined.
    window.exampleObject.setWidth(6);
    console.log(window.exampleObject);
});
```

If things aren't clear please ask.

Note: A json call does not work with local file storage. You will need something lime xamp to run this yourself.

Comment: Have `file2.js` define a function (say, `function runAfterFetchingSettings() { ... }`instead of declaring a `ready` listener, and call that function inside your `getJSON` callback (or inside the `always` handler, whichever) where your set `example`.

Comment: @apsillers That will make file1.js dependend on file2.js tho. Is there a way that if file2 would not exist file1 could still continu without throwing errors ?

Comment: Oh, yes: store the Deferred that `getJSON` returns in a global (say, `settingsFetch = $.getJSON(...)`) and call `settingsFetch.then(function (){...})` in file2.

Comment: @apsillers That works perfectly thank you. If you want you can create an answer so i can mark it.

Comment: I've closed this under a master duplicate for questions of this type -- it goes into a lot more depth than any quick answer I could give! (But I'm glad my solution worked `:)`) Check out the section on Promises and Deferred for a more in-depth look at your situation.